# How to Update Google Calendar when an Object Record is Created in Salesforce

Tags: community

Updating Google Calendar when an Object Record is Created

Comment: extending @Seb Wagner's alternative: in an Insert Trigger, use the GData toolkit to make a Web Service Callout to Google and make sure to handle the responses accordingly

Answer (score 2):

depending on your specific requirements you might get away with a package from the AppEx
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=Google%20Calendar

alternative you have to build something on your own using the GData toolkit
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Data_API_Toolkit